# How can I import researchpy in Jupyter?

Tags: python

After a succesfull `pip install of (python3) researchpy` I cannot start it in Jupyter. When I am trying to run `import researchypy` I get an error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xEFn0.png)

Can anyone help me? Thy in advance!

Comment: Can you please post the code that throws the error?

Comment: is researchypy installed?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow! researchpy requires Python 3.6+ (the error happens on an f-string, which is a Python 3.6+ feature). What Python version are you using?

Comment: Hi Quentin, thy, I have 3.5.2. this can be the problem. So I should refresh python to 3.6.

Comment: Yes, this is certainly one problem that you need to fix! If there are other issues feel free to ask another question.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have both `python-2` and `python-3` installed on your system and as default `python-2` is set for `pip`.

So please try the below and install.

`pip3 install  researchpy`

The above will explicitly install packages in `python-3`.

Comment: Hi Ashwin, thy, I did it by using pip3. Quentin has mentioned above that researchpy needs python 3.6+ and I have only 3.5.2.

Answer (score 0):

When you have this problem you can try upgrade your package. In this case, try to use:

```
pip install --upgrade researchpy
```